# Why should an electronic circuit system be linear in order to use Fourier and Laplace transforms?

Tags: fourier, laplace-transform, linear

What I understood is, if we need to analyze a data from a system (such as damped oscillation or an output of an electronic circuit), the system must act in linear fashion to employ Fourier and Laplace transforms. Why is that? I thought any signal could be decomposed as sinusoid. I mean, if one acquires data from a system why does that data have to be obtained from a linear system to employ Fourier and Laplace transforms?

Comment: What makes you think Laplace and Fourier transforms are not used to analyze non linear systems? Try a simple Google - laplace transforms in non linear systems

Comment: sorry it is because where i work they make data acquisition for damped oscillation vibration systems. they acquire data only in linear behavior range. i thought they do it to employ FFT.

Comment: That's fine - just be grateful your systems are so well behaved.

Comment: If the system is described as nonlinear differential equation can we still employ Fourier or Laplace transforms?

Comment: By their nature nonlinear differential equations tend to require unique solutions rather than a general solution. Personally I'd leave it to a mathematician to sort out - they love that sort of thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because a nonlinear system doesn't benefit from the superposition property, that is essential to use the transforms. Another property that is not valid for nonlinear system is the homogeneity.

The only solution is find the equilibrium point, because for little excursions from this point you have a linear system, and you can approximate the behavior of the system by this way.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is taking the Laplace transforms of the input and output signals, the problem is that only linear systems have a simple relationship between the two (i.e. if the input is \$x(t)\$ whose Laplace transform is \$X(s)\$ and the corresponding output is \$y(t)\$ whose Laplace transform is \$Y(s)\$, then for linear systems \$Y(s)=H(s) X(s)\$, for non linear systems the relationship is more complex).

Comment: u mean complex that even a software like MATLAB cannot handle it? If the system is described as nonlinear differential equation can we still employ Fourier or Laplace transforms?

Comment: I'm not up to date in techniques used for non linear systems. The one I remember started by linearizing the system around an operating point and then analyzing the difference between that and the true system, for the first step, linear analysis was useful.

Comment: @user16307, if you're looking at the input and output of a nonlinear system, you can still use Fourier analysis to describe those signals in spectral terms. But you can't write a simple multiplicative transfer function H(f) or H(s) that describes the behavior of the system. For some types of nonlinear systems you can use related methods such as *harmonic balance* or *X-parameters*.

Answer (score 0):

In simplest terms, a linear system is one in which the values of its components do not change their values when subjected to voltages or currents.  If a large voltage, for example, causes the component value to change (perhaps due to reaching saturation limits of that component) then either you must restrict the in voltage to the smaller values or you can describe the system as a series of "piece wise" linear portions for which the system can be viewed as linear in each range: similar to taking a curve (non-linear V - I characteristics of a system) and redrawing it as a series of straight lines.  As a result, you get different (linear) system functions in each range.  Then the Laplace transform solution can be applied separately for each linear range.

Answer (score 0):

One can compute a Fourier transform of any physical signal, whether that signal is obtained by means of a linear processing or a nonlinear one. That is what a signal analyser does on the lab bench, by the way. A spectrum analyser which is probing the output of, say an oscillator, does that too, but it performs only an amplitude measurement while giving no information about phase... As far as Fourier transforms are concerned, the difference between a linear system and a nonlinear one, is that one can express the Fourier transform of the output of a linear system as the product of the input signal's transform and of a function of frequency which is independant of that input. There is no such relationship in the case of a nonlinear system, although the Fourier transform of that latter system's output does exist.